# IF and exceptions in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to ask you about the Interrupt flag (IF) in linux, if IF==0 we can't get interrupts but can we get exceptions ? (You know there is a difference between exceptions and interrupts)

Comment: Why are you thanking your forehead? Also, try accepting some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular exception you're thinking of? The usual bunch -- page faults, undefined opcodes, privilege violations and so forth -- surely has to lead to *some* form of behavior if the processor encounters them. In most cases, ignoring the exception is not even a meaningful option: how do you ignore a page fault? Pretend the virtual address is mapped to some random physical address?

So they will be handled, IF or no IF.